# Theoretical calculation of gate delay

Tags: circuit-analysis, logic-gates, cmos, delay, small-signal

I am currently working on not-gate based ring oscillators and I was wondering if there was a way to theoretically calculate without having to look at the simulation graphs the rise time and fall time of a gate.

For example, if this is my gate:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvawhU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

(assume that \$k_{p2}=k_{n1}=0.0734\$, \$V_\text{th1}=V_\text{th2}=0.26V\$. You can take further assumptions if needed, please specify them if taken)

How do I theoretically calculate the rise time and the fall time of my gate? It would be helpful if a numerical answer could be provided.

Comment: You must specify the input capacitance of the NOT gate, the trace capacitance of the input trace and the output impedance of the signal source. Otherwise, the delay will be zero. For final settling the power supply impedance of VDD and VSS is also important.

Comment: ok, can you assume some valid values and provide me a way to calculate the gate delay?

Comment: also, assume no impedances from power sources

Comment: Then the delay will be on the order of R*C.

Comment: how do you obtain that particular R was what I was wondering.

Comment: It is the driver impedance. I don't know what typical values are for your design situation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146507/discussion-between-kabe2003-and-tobalt).

Comment: You should be aware that a hand calculation is going to be fairly crude. You really should run a simulation of the actual circuit, including parasitic capacitances from wiring.

Comment: can I use a method like small signal analysis if I know about the physical parameters of a MOSFET to get an approximate estimate of the delay time?

Comment: A ring-oscillator made with inverters is very much a large-signal situation, so a small-signal analysis would again be an extremely crude approximation. Simulation is the way to go.